# Prefil Google Places Placer Picker search bar on Android?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-places, android-search

I dont see an official way, is there a workaround to prefill the search bar (and perform search) in the Google Places API's Place Picker for android?

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker

Thanks!

As of the post, using the latest Google Play Services 10.2.1

Comment: For features not currently supported:
A good rule of thumb is, if it is not documented, it is not available to us. You may want to file a feature request as discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/support#issue-tracker).